# Framework7+vue side panel contents are not getting updated after login

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

I have a side panel with some links for public users that does not require to login and some private users links that requires to login into the app. My problem is that after login the panel is not getting updated unless I reload the app. Is there any solution to solve this problem? Below is my code snippets:
 1. Template code:
[image]

2. vue code:
   [image]

Comment: Could you post some example code that you have done to update the side panel? Is the panel, a component by itself? You could probably use vuex so that you can reference values to display the links you require when the user has logged in. Hard to provide help or insight unless you show something you have done.

Comment: I have updated the thread with the code snippets screen shot and I use vuex to manage this but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it by making menu as component and put :key attribute then increase key value by 1 each time the component loads.

[image]

[image]